# Keyboard shows up automatically when the app starts in Xamarin WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hello everyone recently I am working on the project which related to the hybrid webview in xamarin and keyboard hides input field. So in order to solve this problem I used this
*Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize | SoftInput.StateVisible);*
inside OnCreate method.Every thing is fine but the keyboard shows up automatically when the app starts. Please help me.

```
namespace CheongnyeonNara.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "Young", 
    Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", 
    Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", 
    MainLauncher = true, 
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | 
    ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        //ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

        UserDialogs.Init(this);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
         
        App app = new App();
        LoadApplication(app);
        Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize | SoftInput.StateVisible);      
         
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, 
    [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
        grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `SoftInput.StateVisible` ,the soft keyboard is visible when that's normally appropriate (when the user is navigating forward to the activity's main window).It will automatically pop up the software keyboard when you enter the Activity.

Comment: thank you. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to remove `SoftInput.StateVisible` ?

Comment: I did everything but it didn't help me. But when I created project with xamarin android it works

Comment: Could you show some screenshots of run in xamarin.android and in xamarin.forms ?